# CSS selectors: What am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply different styles for even and odd elements of those which have a special class. But parity is considered to be relative to the entire list, not to the list of items with special class. How can i do this with pure css without js?

```css
.item {
  height: 20px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  outline: 1px dotted orange;
}

.item._special:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: skyblue;
}

.item._special:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<section class="list">
  <div class="item _special">odd</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item _special">even</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item _special">odd</div>
</section>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is `nth-of-class`, which doesn't exist. `nth-of-type` selects the **type** of the element.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468639/how-to-use-nth-of-type-for-classes-not-elements

Comment: @Vucko Thank you for the answer. It means it can not be solved by using pure CSS, only JS?

Comment: @Roberrrt Thank you, I had to look harder.

Comment: I've tried 'hacking' some CSS together, but I can't find a sustainable way. JS would be the way to go, yes.